# OKTA API not exporting Source address details

Tags: api, okta

I have created an OKTA API using token and admin account url to export the events(logs) reffered to the activities done on my okta account.
i am able to export the events but the IP address details or the source IP (from where) info is not getting exported.
anything more need to added to API for the same. please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Modify Okta API com.okta.sdk.models.event.Actor.java
Add a property:
private String ipAddress;

Add get/set funcitons.
Compile source code to a new Okta API jar, use this jar substitute the original one, then you will get your IpAddress attribute value in event.actor.ipAddress

Answer (score 0):

The ipAddress depends on the Actor objectType. Events with a Client ObjectType will include the ipAddress as shown in the example below:

{
    "id": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36",
    "displayName": "CHROME",
    "ipAddress": "127.0.0.1",
    "objectType": "Client"
}

One way to debug this would be to use the public Events API and filter the events to validate that for the ipAddress is getting captured for the appropriate Events. If the ipAddress is included in the JSON response but is not getting parsed in the CSV export, then you may have uncovered a bug. That said, I just tested this and it worked for me ;-)

Comment: thanks Benjamin, actually when i export the events into CSV format from OKTA UI it provides the source address details. but when i call the events from API source address doesn't seems to be exported. here is a sample log in JSON format which i got after calling from API.

Comment: {"eventId":"tevLRM2cnRAQ66spls2gA1A9g1426836357112","published":"2015-03-20T07:25:57Z","requestId":"VQvLhRrgZ5ns@@TVApF3hwAAEYU","sessionId":"","action":{"message":"Sign-in Failed - Unknown User 'shwetank'","categories":["Sign-in Failure","Suspicious Activity"],"objectType":"core.user_auth.login_failed","requestUri":"/login/do-login"},"actors":[{"id":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0","displayName":"FIREFOX","objectType":"Client"}],"targets":[{"id":"","displayName":null,"objectType":"User"}]}